# Mongo aggregation best approach

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

After doing some aggregation on my data Im left with the following data:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "incomeAccountName" : "Kaffe/Te",
    "type" : "REFUND"
},
"amounts" : [ 
    [ 
        {
            "amount" : -78.0,
            "currency" : "SEK"
        }
    ], 
    [ 
        {
            "amount" : -34.0,
            "currency" : "SEK"
        }
    ]
],
"items" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Latte mellan",
        "amounts" : [ 
            {
                "amount" : -78.0,
                "currency" : "SEK"
            }
        ],
        "taxAmounts" : [ 
            {
                "amount" : -8.35714626312256,
                "currency" : "SEK"
            }
        ],
        "quantity" : -2.0,
        "itemType" : "ARTICLE"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Bryggkaffe",
        "amounts" : [ 
            {
                "amount" : -34.0,
                "currency" : "SEK"
            }
        ],
        "taxAmounts" : [ 
            {
                "amount" : -3.64285850524902,
                "currency" : "SEK"
            }
        ],
        "quantity" : -1.0,
        "itemType" : "ARTICLE"
    }
]
}
```

Now I want to reduce amounts to:

```
amounts: [
           {
             "amount":-112,
             "currency":"SEK"
           }
         ]
```

That is, calculate sum/currency. Notice we could have multiple currencies. What is the best approach to do this with aggregations without affecting the rest of the data set? I am using mongo 3.4.

The original data looks like:

```
    [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac1e43e24cc2974c7cda7a9"),
    "alias" : "d89135d0-1067-46a9-92f3-44b1c4373612",
    "billAlias" : "439d2e1c-0e7b-4521-960f-2bf87de90044",
    "status" : "COMPLETE",
    "type" : "PAYMENT",
    "started" : ISODate("2018-04-02T08:05:17.937Z"),
    "completed" : ISODate("2018-04-02T08:05:17.937Z"),
    "merchant" : {
        "merchantId" : "110b5def-3516-484a-9dc0-1fb9326488b0",
        "terminalId" : "951321001",
        "cashierId" : "598c22920cf27724adf035fa",
        "placeAlias" : "20939de7-34bc-47a7-b04e-0df4864271ee",
        "menuAlias" : "a3ac290d-a2b8-4e59-aea4-bbdf7106f2a2"
    },
    "currency" : "SEK",
    "orderRows" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Soppbuffé 98kr",
            "itemType" : "ARTICLE",
            "group" : "Varm Mat",
            "incomeAccountName" : "Kall/varm mat",
            "articleId" : "56aca26a-18ae-4079-8968-dd9cd3066168",
            "extArticleId" : "1662",
            "amount" : 98.0,
            "amountInclDiscount" : 88.1999969482422,
            "singleAmount" : 98.0,
            "vatPercent" : 12.0,
            "vatAmount" : 10.5000038146973,
            "vatAmountInclDiscount" : 9.4500036239624,
            "itemCount" : 1.0,
            "ignoreDiscount" : false,
            "cashierId" : "598c22920cf27724adf035fa",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-02T10:04:56.056Z")
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Studentrabatt 10%",
            "itemType" : "DISCOUNT",
            "group" : "RABATT",
            "incomeAccountName" : "Rabatt/Discount",
            "amount" : -9.80000019073486,
            "amountInclDiscount" : -9.80000019073486,
            "singleAmount" : -9.80000019073486,
            "vatPercent" : 0.0,
            "vatAmount" : -1.05000042915344,
            "vatAmountInclDiscount" : -1.05000042915344,
            "itemCount" : 1.0,
            "ignoreDiscount" : false,
            "discountPercent" : 10.0
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac1e44224cc2974c7cda7ab"),
    "alias" : "696ff805-0a43-4904-b1bc-f46847b4ab67",
    "billAlias" : "dc49c822-6d74-4c70-80a7-aa5106666817",
    "status" : "COMPLETE",
    "type" : "PAYMENT",
    "started" : ISODate("2018-04-02T08:05:21.998Z"),
    "completed" : ISODate("2018-04-02T08:05:21.998Z"),
    "merchant" : {
        "merchantId" : "110b5def-3516-484a-9dc0-1fb9326488b0",
        "terminalId" : "951321003",
        "cashierId" : "598c22920cf27724adf035fa",
        "placeAlias" : "20939de7-34bc-47a7-b04e-0df4864271ee",
        "menuAlias" : "a3ac290d-a2b8-4e59-aea4-bbdf7106f2a2"
    },
    "currency" : "SEK",
    "orderRows" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Soppbuffé 98kr",
            "itemType" : "ARTICLE",
            "group" : "Varm Mat",
            "incomeAccountName" : "Kall/varm mat",
            "articleId" : "56aca26a-18ae-4079-8968-dd9cd3066168",
            "extArticleId" : "1662",
            "amount" : 98.0,
            "amountInclDiscount" : 88.1999969482422,
            "singleAmount" : 98.0,
            "vatPercent" : 12.0,
            "vatAmount" : 10.5000038146973,
            "vatAmountInclDiscount" : 9.4500036239624,
            "itemCount" : 1.0,
            "ignoreDiscount" : false,
            "cashierId" : "598c22920cf27724adf035fa",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-02T10:05:05.005Z")
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Studentrabatt 10%",
            "itemType" : "DISCOUNT",
            "group" : "RABATT",
            "incomeAccountName" : "Rabatt/Discount",
            "amount" : -9.80000019073486,
            "amountInclDiscount" : -9.80000019073486,
            "singleAmount" : -9.80000019073486,
            "vatPercent" : 0.0,
            "vatAmount" : -1.05000042915344,
            "vatAmountInclDiscount" : -1.05000042915344,
            "itemCount" : 1.0,
            "ignoreDiscount" : false,
            "discountPercent" : 10.0
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac1e4a424cc2974c7cda7bd"),
    "alias" : "f14f13a5-6f16-41ef-ac57-a511f394bf32",
    "billAlias" : "04522348-d48d-4273-a511-09035666ced9",
    "status" : "COMPLETE",
    "type" : "PAYMENT",
    "started" : ISODate("2018-04-02T08:07:00.618Z"),
    "completed" : ISODate("2018-04-02T08:07:00.618Z"),
    "merchant" : {
        "merchantId" : "110b5def-3516-484a-9dc0-1fb9326488b0",
        "terminalId" : "951321001",
        "cashierId" : "598c22920cf27724adf035fa",
        "placeAlias" : "20939de7-34bc-47a7-b04e-0df4864271ee",
        "menuAlias" : "a3ac290d-a2b8-4e59-aea4-bbdf7106f2a2"
    },
    "currency" : "SEK",
    "orderRows" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Chévre Honey",
            "itemType" : "ARTICLE",
            "group" : "Kall Mat",
            "incomeAccountName" : "Kall/varm mat",
            "articleId" : "d8e49d26-30b8-4237-96ef-07bea2961537",
            "extArticleId" : "1636",
            "amount" : 99.0,
            "amountInclDiscount" : 89.0999984741211,
            "singleAmount" : 99.0,
            "vatPercent" : 12.0,
            "vatAmount" : 10.6071472167969,
            "vatAmountInclDiscount" : 9.54643249511719,
            "itemCount" : 1.0,
            "ignoreDiscount" : false,
            "cashierId" : "598c22920cf27724adf035fa",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-02T10:05:59.059Z")
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Bryggkaffe",
            "itemType" : "ARTICLE",
            "group" : "Varma drycker",
            "incomeAccountName" : "Kaffe/Te",
            "articleId" : "36672f69-6ac5-419e-a195-b3b0fcdf63b6",
            "extArticleId" : "1608",
            "amount" : 34.0,
            "amountInclDiscount" : 30.6000003814697,
            "singleAmount" : 34.0,
            "vatPercent" : 12.0,
            "vatAmount" : 3.64285850524902,
            "vatAmountInclDiscount" : 3.27857279777527,
            "itemCount" : 1.0,
            "ignoreDiscount" : false,
            "cashierId" : "598c22920cf27724adf035fa",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-02T10:06:23.023Z")
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Studentrabatt 10%",
            "itemType" : "DISCOUNT",
            "group" : "RABATT",
            "incomeAccountName" : "Rabatt/Discount",
            "amount" : -13.3000001907349,
            "amountInclDiscount" : -13.3000001907349,
            "singleAmount" : -13.3000001907349,
            "vatPercent" : 0.0,
            "vatAmount" : -1.42500054836273,
            "vatAmountInclDiscount" : -1.42500054836273,
            "itemCount" : 1.0,
            "ignoreDiscount" : false,
            "discountPercent" : 10.0
        }
    ]
}]
```

My current aggregation pipeline looks like:

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
    {$match: {"merchant.merchantId": "110b5def-3516-484a-9dc0-1fb9326488b0", status: "COMPLETE",completed : {$gte:  ISODate("2018-04-02T00:46:12.331Z"), $lte: ISODate("2018-04-12T10:46:12.331Z")}}},
    {$addFields: {"orderRows.discountName": {$arrayElemAt: [ {$filter: {input: "$orderRows",as: "orderRow",cond: { $eq:['$$orderRow.itemType','DISCOUNT'] }}},0]}}},
    {$project: {currency:1,type:1, orderRows: {$map: {input: '$orderRows', as:'orderRow', in : {$cond: [{ '$eq': [ '$$orderRow.discountName', undefined ] }, ['$$orderRow'], ['$$orderRow',{name:'$$orderRow.discountName.name',amount:{$subtract: [ '$$orderRow.amountInclDiscount', '$$orderRow.amount' ]},vatAmount:{$subtract: [ '$$orderRow.vatAmountInclDiscount', '$$orderRow.vatAmount' ]},incomeAccountName:{$concat:['$$orderRow.incomeAccountName',' - Rabatt']},itemType:'$$orderRow.itemType',itemCount:1.0}]]}}}}},
    {$unwind : '$orderRows'},
    {$project: {currency:1,type:1, orderRows: {$filter: {input: "$orderRows",as: "orderRow",cond: { $ne:['$$orderRow.itemType','DISCOUNT'] }}} }},
    {$unwind : '$orderRows'},
    {$group : {_id: {incomeAccountName:'$orderRows.incomeAccountName',currency:'$currency',articleName:'$orderRows.name',type:'$type'},itemType:{$max:'$orderRows.itemType'},amount:{$sum:'$orderRows.amount'},taxAmount:{$sum:'$orderRows.vatAmount'},quantity:{$sum:'$orderRows.itemCount'}}},
    {$group : {_id: {incomeAccountName:'$_id.incomeAccountName',articleName:'$_id.articleName',type:'$_id.type'},itemType:{$max:'$itemType'},quantity:{$max:'$quantity'},amounts:{$push:{amount:'$amount',currency:'$_id.currency'}},taxAmounts:{$push:{amount:'$taxAmount',currency:'$_id.currency'}}}},
    {$group : {_id: {incomeAccountName:'$_id.incomeAccountName',type:'$_id.type'},amounts:{$push:{amount:{$sum:'$amounts.amount'},currency:'$amounts.currency'}},items:{$push:{name:'$_id.articleName',amounts:'$amounts',taxAmounts:'$taxAmounts',quantity:'$quantity',itemType:'$itemType'}}}},
])
```

Comment: In all honesty, the "best" thing to do here is show us some source data to reproduce a result, and show your existing pipeline. Chances are you may not have taken the "best" approach to get to your current point given the eventual outcome you want. That would be better for you than simply throwing *"one more aggregation stage"* at something that may need to be optimized before that.

Comment: Point being, you could simply "tack on" a `$reduce` within an `$addFields` to reshape the array, but my bet says we could "sum those together" before you get "arrays of arrays" as you presently have. So better to fix the underlying construction.

Comment: @Frej , please post your data set and  aggregation query ..

Comment: @NeilLunn Updated my question with details regarding the original data and my aggregation

Comment: That's a bit better. But the source document does not match the current output you have posted. From the single document you give here your current aggregation produces two documents, and these only list one item inside the `amounts` array, where you seem to intend to "sum" these together. So could you provide a better source sample, and make sure it demonstrates what you want as well as updating your expected output to be based on exactly what can actually be output from that sample.

Comment: @NeilLunn Updated both the data set and my current pipeline

Comment: @RahulRaj updated data set and current query

Comment: Well the current pipeline could certainly be improved. Not sure if I get the overall logic though. If I interpret correctly, then the output expected would be for each of the 2 `"incomeAccountName"` values with their respective items and NET ( total - discount ) amounts, and then those same two `"incomeAccountName"` showing the respective detail for any "discounts" applied. Per "item" in each case, and then summarized total. Does that sound right? It's just that you are creating arrays all over the place for "singular" values that would not appear to "need" to be in an array.